# ffmpeg black bars at the left and right side of the video

Tags: conversion, ffmpeg, resolution

I have strange problem with the resolution using ffmpeg. in the output bellow I've two files "test1" and "test2".

**"test1.flv"** I've downloaded from website and it was already converted into flv, and **test2.flv** i've converted myself.
now the issue is, my file has black bars on the left and the right side of the video. while they both have the same resolution test1 doesn't have any bars at all.

```
fmpeg -loglevel panic -i "test.avi" -vf "movie=/storage/conv_sctipt/watermark.mov  [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10, fade=in:0:20 [out]" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -y -acodec libfaac -ab 64K -ac 1 -vcodec libx264 -b 555K -bt 666k -threads 0 "test2.flv"
```

ffmpeg -i test2.flv

```
**test2.flv**
ffmpeg version git-2012-05-17-a99a3b1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 17 2012 23:39:57 with gcc 4.6.2
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      51. 53.100 / 51. 53.100
  libavcodec     54. 21.101 / 54. 21.101
  libavformat    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 74.100 /  2. 74.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 11.100 /  0. 11.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
  Metadata:
    metadatacreator : Yet Another Metadata Injector for FLV - Version 1.4
    hasKeyframes    : true
    hasVideo        : true
    hasAudio        : true
    hasMetadata     : true
    canSeekToEnd    : true
    datasize        : 103188591
    videosize       : 91604369
    audiosize       : 11214994
    lasttimestamp   : 1303
    lastkeyframetimestamp: 1303
    lastkeyframelocation: 103194425
  Duration: 00:21:42.72, start: 0.021000, bitrate: 633 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 720x400 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:5], 560 kb/s, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
root@host-37:/# 
root@host-37:/#
```

ffmpeg -i test1.flv

```
**test1.flv**
ffmpeg version git-2012-05-17-a99a3b1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 17 2012 23:39:57 with gcc 4.6.2
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      51. 53.100 / 51. 53.100
  libavcodec     54. 21.101 / 54. 21.101
  libavformat    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 74.100 /  2. 74.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 11.100 /  0. 11.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
  Metadata:
    metadatacreator : Yet Another Metadata Injector for FLV - Version 1.8
    hasKeyframes    : true
    hasVideo        : true
    hasAudio        : true
    hasMetadata     : true
    canSeekToEnd    : false
    datasize        : 116774820
    videosize       : 95577067
    audiosize       : 20591541
    lasttimestamp   : 2435
    lastkeyframetimestamp: 2433
    lastkeyframelocation: 116745006
  Duration: 00:40:34.52, start: 0.040000, bitrate: 383 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 720x400 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:5], 311 kb/s, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: The output of `ffmpeg -i test1.flv` would be useful as well for comparison. `-bt 666k` is ignored by libx264 and `-threads 0` (as in "auto") should be default, so these options are superfluous. What player are you using to display the videos?

Comment: your have the output of ffmpeg -i test1.flv from **test1.flv** till the end... uppod

Comment: What player are you using to display the videos?

Comment: it was the actual watermark.mov that caused the problem, not sure why but switching to png image solved the problem for me

Comment: Next time include the complete console outputs for each command. This would have made the issue more apparent. You should use `-filter_complex` instead of `-vf` with multiple inputs: `ffmpeg -i test.avi -i watermark.mov -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10, fade=in:0:20 [out]" ... output`